# htaccess for subdomain.example.com instead of example.com/subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I want to create a `.htaccess` file to use http://subdomain.example.com instead of http://www.example.com/subdomain/

How can I create this `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: Please provide more information than that. What have you tried? Why isn't it working? As it is now your question is too broad for SO. Please read the help entry about asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't know what to write for htaccess, I'm asking what to write to htaccess to do this